# How to inject properties on an interface properly in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have done this several times before, and I know this is how styled-components "themes" work, where you can define your own theme properties, and it TypeScript-autocompletes those properties deeply inside a styled-component. You essentially do this:

```
import { MyTheme } from '~/configurations'

declare module 'styled-components' {
  interface DefaultTheme extends MyTheme {}
}
```

And then in `./configurations/index.ts`, we have:

```
const theme = {
  fonts: {
    font1: 'foo'
  },
  colors: {
    red: 'bar'
  }
}

export type MyTheme = typeof theme
```

That `DefaultTheme` is being dynamically extended *from the outside* by my theme. So everything inside the styled-components library can be typed according to my theme.

So why isn't it working when I try to implement this functionality from scratch?

Here is what I have, I have created a [TypeScript library](https://github.com/lancejpollard/halt.js) which is 1 file, like this:

```
import { CustomError } from 'ts-custom-error'

export class Halt extends CustomError {
  form: keyof HaltList

  link: HaltLink

  static list: HaltList = {}

  // make your codes cool.
  static code: (code: number) => string = (code: number) =>
    code.toString(16).padStart(4, '0').toUpperCase()

  // your template for rendering codes.
  static make: (code: string, note: string) => string = (
    code: string,
    note: string,
  ) => `[${code}] ${note}`

  constructor(form: keyof HaltList, link: HaltLink = {}) {
    if (!(form in Halt.list)) {
      throw new Error(`Name ${form} missing from halt list`)
    }

    const hook = Halt.list[form]

    if (!hook) {
      throw new Error(`Hook ${form} is missing from halt list`)
    }

    const note =
      typeof hook.note === 'function' ? hook.note(link) : hook.note
    const code = Halt.code(hook.code)
    const text = Halt.make(code, note)

    super(text)

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'form', {
      enumerable: false,
      value: form,
    })

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'link', {
      enumerable: false,
      value: link,
    })

    this.form = form
    this.link = link

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', { value: 'Halt' })
  }

  toJSON() {
    const hook = Halt.list[this.form]

    if (!hook) {
      throw new Error()
    }

    const note =
      typeof hook.note === 'function' ? hook.note(this.link) : hook.note
    const code = Halt.code(hook.code)
    const term = hook.term

    return { code, note, term }
  }
}

export type HaltHook = {
  code: number
  hint?: string | ((link: HaltLink) => string)
  note: string | ((link: HaltLink) => string)
  term?: Array<string> | ((link: HaltLink) => Array<string>)
}

export type HaltLink = Record<string, unknown>

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions
export interface HaltList {
  [key: string]: HaltHook
}

export function assertHalt(x: unknown): asserts x is Halt {
  if (!isHalt(x)) {
    throw new Error('Error is not a halt. ' + (x as Error).message)
  }
}

export function isHalt(x: unknown): x is Halt {
  return x instanceof Halt
}

export default function halt(
  form: keyof HaltList,
  link: HaltLink = {},
) {
  throw new Halt(form, link)
}
```

In there, I have the `HaltList` which I want to dynamically inject properties onto, so when I do this, I get code completion for TypeScript:

```
halt('
```

It should show the properties I have defined in my custom code, which might look like this (in `./configurations/errors`):

```
import { Halt } from '@lancejpollard/halt.js'

const HALT = {
  missing_property: {
    code: 1,
    note: 'Property missing',
  },
}

export type HaltType = typeof HALT

Halt.list = HALT
```

And then I try and inject it in like this, with a `test.d.ts` file at the base of my project:

```
import { HaltType } from './configurations/errors'

declare module '@lancejpollard/halt.js' {
  export interface HaltList extends HaltType {}
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. How can I get this so that `HaltList` now has my `missing_property` on it, so when I do `halt('` it autocompletes with `missing_property` (and it throws errors if you try and use something not defined in that extended interface)?

### Update

My usage is like this:

```
import { Halt } from '@lancejpollard/halt.js'

const HALT = {
  invalid_form: {
    code: 3,
    note: ({ name }) => `Form '${name}' is not valid`,
  },
  invalid_type: {
    code: 2,
    note: ({ name, type }) => `Value '${name}' is not '${type}' type`,
  },
  missing_property: {
    code: 1,
    note: ({ name }) => `Property '${name}' missing`,
  },
}

export { Halt }

export type HaltType = typeof HALT

Halt.list = HALT
```

Then in another file:

```
throw new Halt('missing_property')
// or
halt('missing_property')
```

This works in terms of autocompleting at `halt('missing_`), but it throws an error at `Halt.list = HALT` saying:

```
Type '{ invalid_form: { code: number; host: string; note: ({ name }: { name: any; }) => string; }; invalid_type: { code: number; host: string; note: ({ name, type }: { name: any; type: any; }) => string; }; missing_property: { code: number; host: string; note: ({ name }: { ...; }) => string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'HaltList'.
  Property 'invalid_form' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ code: number; host: string; note: ({ name }: { name: any; }) => string; }' is not assignable to type 'HaltHook'.
      Types of property 'note' are incompatible.
        Type '({ name }: { name: any; }) => string' is not assignable to type 'string | ((link: HaltLink) => string)'.
          Type '({ name }: { name: any; }) => string' is not assignable to type '(link: HaltLink) => string'.
            Types of parameters '__0' and 'link' are incompatible.
              Property 'name' is missing in type 'HaltLink' but required in type '{ name: any; }'.
```

So I try this:

```
import { Halt, HaltList } from "@lancejpollard/halt.js";

const HALT: HaltList = {
// ... rest
```

And now the autocomplete breaks and says:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

At the location of `halt('missing_property')`.

Comment: It appears maybe it's not loading the `controller.d.ts` for some reason? I made some progress and now am getting `Could not find a declaration file for module 'x'`, where x is one of my homemade plain JS (not TS) modules, which I declared in a local .d.ts. So it's not picking that up either it looks like. Any ideas?

Comment: The use of a `.d.ts` file here seems unnecessary. Why not just declare `Handle` like `export interface Handle extends HandleType {}` directly in `types.ts`? You'll still get declaration merging. There's almost certainly a way to split out and push down the common deps to avoid the circular problem -- but I think I'd need a codesandbox to fully understand it as its quite hard to dry run in my head

Comment: @adsy I have changed the example to a simpler example I think, where I have created an external library and am trying to inject properties from my app into the library.

Answer (score 0):

By typing

```
type a = HaltList['missing_property']
//   ^?
```

you can make sure the type merging *does works* (if it's not, write in the comments)

Your problem is that you can't just `keyof (Record<string, V> & { k: V1 })` as you'll just get `string`

To get the `keyof` you want rather then `keyof` you have you need to remove the index signatures:

https://tsplay.dev/Nr93zw

```
// import type { OmitIndexSignature } from 'type-fest' // doesn't work on Playground, so
type OmitIndexSignature<ObjectType> = {
    [KeyType in keyof ObjectType as {} extends Record<KeyType, unknown>
        ? never
        : KeyType]: ObjectType[KeyType];
};

export default function halt(
  form: keyof OmitIndexSignature<HaltList>
) {}

type a = Exclude<keyof HaltList, 'missing_property'>
//   ^? type a = string | number
type b = HaltList['missing_property']
//   ^? type b = { code: number; note: string; }

halt('')
//    ^| missing_property

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// file A.ts
const HALT = {
  missing_property: {
    code: 1,
    note: 'Property missing',
  },
}
export type HaltType = typeof HALT
// declare module '@me/lib/B.ts'
  export interface HaltList extends HaltType {}
// }
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// fine B.ts
export type HaltHook = {
  code: number
  hint?: string | ((link: URL) => string)
  note: string | ((link: URL) => string)
  term?: Array<string> | ((link: URL) => Array<string>)
}
export interface HaltList {
  [key: string]: HaltHook
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: If this take on a question is correct, please rename is to smth like `How to use 'keyof' on <question>`

Comment: I'm [getting this](https://imgur.com/a/XPwd5PV): `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` on `halt('foo')`. I updated the repo example.ts if you want to see. https://github.com/lancejpollard/halt.js/blob/make/test.ts

Comment: I updated the question with an **update** showing what's going wrong, from two angles.

Comment: @Lance the new error is clearly `let a: Record<string, unknown> = { a: 1 }; let b: { name: string } = a`. Either `{ name?: string }` or `Record<string, unknown> & { name: string }`